# Flash popup from within decorator function on Flask Route

Tags: python, flask

I would like to create a `flash` popup from within a decorator function applied to a Flask view. When I generate a `flash` from within my view, everything works perfectly fine. I would like to be able to also generate flash messages from a wrapper function acting on the view; the form I have tried is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from functools import wraps

def my_wrapper_function(_f):
    @wraps(_f)
    def _decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
       ...
       flash(removed_article.get('name', 'expansion'))
       ...
       return _f(*args, **kwargs)

    return _decorated_function


@app.route('/my_view/<int:_id>', methods=['GET'])
@my_wrapper_function
def my_view(_id):
   ...
   return render_template('my_template.jinja2')
```

This does not appear to work however, no flash message appears.
N.B: As opposed to generating flash messages *within* my view, which **does** work.

The following template is included below for completeness; I would imagine the solution lies in the python code.

```
# my_template.jinja2
 {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
      {% if messages %}
        {% for category, message in messages %}
            {% if category == 'message' %}
              <div class="alert alert-success text-center" role="alert">
            {% else %}
              <div class="alert alert-{{ category }} text-center" role="alert">
            {% endif %}
              {{ message }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
  {% endwith %}
```

Since I'm fairly new at both decorators and Flask in general, I thought I'd ask my fellow S.O wizards for aid.

Thanks in advance for considering my problem:)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was raising the flash in an if statement that was not executed, it has been fixed now.